# Opening creation-is it ever possible?

Tags: opening

I have invented (to the best of my knowledge) a really decent opening. I would like to note that over the ICC I have actually beaten a few masters with this opening, with one master having an ICC rating of 2400 (45 45). I would like to popularize my opening without somebody else stealing it from me, but I really don't know how. Is there a way to do this type of thing?

Comment: Side note: I will not actually say the opening

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stealing it from me"?

Comment: @dfan NP, Lets say I play it against someone, and then that person creates a lecture about it or something like that.

Comment: No, you cannot prevent that.

Comment: You might be right, but lets see if anyone has any ideas

Comment: It might be a bit hard, and will come down mostly to luck, unless you can play it successfully in a major tournament. Many of the openings named after people, are due to large historical significance. Najdorf was not necessarily the first player to play the Najdorf Sicilian, but he managed to get his name attributed to it for other reasons.

Not sure if chess openings are the kinds of things you can copyright.

Comment: What about posting the opening here, or somewhere else, so that no matter what, you could always point to it and say that you made it first. It will be impossible to get into a major tournament and win with the spotlight, unless you're very good.

Comment: Publish in a chess magazine your analysis of the opening. But you have to understand that it is very difficult to discover a TN (theoretical novelty) - a single new move in a known line. Even harder is discovering a sound yet unknown opening.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I checked in three different Chess Databases, each containing zero games.

Comment: Did you show your cash at the 2400+ master in the opening?

Comment: @StudentT what do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Openings cannot be copyrighted, but analysis and comments can be.

The best you can do is probably to publish an extensive analysis of the variation online (or in a magazine, but you should make sure it is available online as well). In that article you should explicitly name the variation. You might also want to throw in some engine-engine games, instead of just concentrating on your own games. Real tournament games would probably be more convincing than online games as well.

If you do that you can always prove precedence by pointing out your article if somebody tries to reinvent and rename the variation. If the article is well written and contains high-level games, it is also quite likely that other people interested in the variation will quote/link you, i.e. accept and cement your precedence.

Comment: Just to point out that opening names can include trademarks, e.g. the Nescafe Frappe attack: 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 c5 3. d5 b5 4. cxb5 a6 5. Nc3 axb5 6. e4 b4 7. Nb5 d6 8. Bc4

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to read the story of the invention of the [Kingston Defence](https://gavinwilson.wordpress.com/2008/03/16/the-kingston-defence-revisited/) by Gavin Wilson. Based on this story I would advise you the following actions:

1. Be sure to triple check your opening hasn't got a name yet. See [here](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http://www.geocities.com/siliconvalley/lab/7378/eco.htm). You never know, it could appear in some obscure publication you don't know about...
2. Work on your opening until you are sure you have analysed all the main responses for white and for black. Better testing it with your computer than against real players at this stage, to diminish the probability of it being "stolen".
3. Find a good name for your opening.
4. Publish your opening, as suggested by BlindKungFuMaster. A book, an article in a chess magazine, an online video... that's up to you.
5. Get some publicity for your opening/publication. See if you can find someone to make a review/comment on your publication. And be sure to play it.